# Wine keeps showing error messages after updating Ubuntu. How to fix?

Tags: wine, games, winetricks

I have been having severe issues with wine on my computer and am wondering if this forum can help. Whenever I try to open a game on Wine, a window with the game icon and an exclamation mark in a red box pops up and loads for a few seconds. After this, a "Program Error" window pops up and says that the program encountered a serious error and needs to close. The window has a button that allows me to see the backtrace. I do not know how to read them and will provide the text to multiple below to help weed out any one time occurrences. I initially thought the issue was with the games needing drivers, since the games I initially was trying to run had been unable to run without them before I updated Ubuntu. However, after trying to install DXVK and trying some other programs, I have come to realize that no program seems to be running on Wine, leading me to believe that the issue is with wine itself. Outside of the games with driver issues, all of the programs have run well multiple times before, so it does not seem to be a compatibility issue. I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and the Q4Wine launcher if that is important. I am willing to answer any quations that may be important to the best of my ability and I thank you in advance.

Edit: I have found a solution to the issue. I downloaded bottles and it not only fixed the issue but installed dxvk in a way that seemed to work, resolving another issue I have been having. I would recommend trying this to anyone having issues. Be warned, bottles does not seem to translate previous save data from before the use of bottles.

```
    Terra Nil:
    Unhandled exception: page fault on execute access to 0x00000000 in 64-bit code (0x0000000000000000).
    
    Register dump:
     rip:0000000000000000 rsp:000000000020f388 rbp:000000007e004610 eflags:00010202 (  R- --  I   - - - )
     
    rax:00000000005f3e70 rbx:0000000000608b80 rcx:00007f70155d4e50 rdx:000000000020f470
     
    rsi:000000000020f500 rdi:000000000020f400  r8:0000000000000000  r9:0000000000000000 
    r10:00000000006c0000
     
    r11:00000000005fb738 r12:0000000000000000 r13:000000000020f7b0 r14:0000000000000000 
    r15:0000000000000001
    
    Stack dump:
    0x000000000020f388:  00000003590d2e7b 00000001c8dd6430
    0x000000000020f398:  00000001c8dd6455 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3a8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3b8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3c8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3d8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3e8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f3f8:  0000000000000000 00000000005d73c0
    0x000000000020f408:  0000000000000000 0000000000000014
    0x000000000020f418:  0000000000000000 000000007dff32f0
    0x000000000020f428:  0000000000000000 0000000000000014
    0x000000000020f438:  0000000000000000 000000003b9fee6e
    
    Backtrace:
    =>0 0x0000000000000000 (0x000000007e004610)
    0x0000000000000000: -- no code accessible --
    
    Modules:
    
    Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (48 modules)
    PE          60950000-        610bf000   Deferred        mono-2.0-bdwgc
    PE          7a850000-        7a854000   Deferred        opengl32
    PE          7b000000-        7b3fd000   Deferred        kernelbase
    PE          7b600000-        7b969000   Deferred        kernel32
    PE          7bc00000-        7bf3c000   Deferred        ntdll
    PE         140000000-       1400a5000   Deferred        terra nil
    PE         180000000-       181bdc000   Deferred        unityplayer
    PE         1c8b40000-       1c8bb7000   Deferred        msacm32
    PE         1c8db0000-       1c9097000   Deferred        msvcrt
    PE         1d97a0000-       1d97ae000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
    PE         1dd3f0000-       1dd758000   Deferred        crypt32
    PE         1f51e0000-       1f5212000   Deferred        hid
    PE         21a7e0000-       21a9ce000   Deferred        setupapi
    PE         231ae0000-       231d60000   Deferred        rpcrt4
    PE         23d820000-       23dfc2000   Deferred        user32
    PE         2419a0000-       241b0c000   Deferred        wbemprox
    PE         25cf30000-       25cf3f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0
    PE         26b4c0000-       26bbb9000   Deferred        gdi32
    PE         2739c0000-       273ec9000   Deferred        oleaut32
    PE         28ebe0000-       28ebef000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
    PE         2ba290000-       2ba29f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0
    PE         2d4d40000-       2d4d96000   Deferred        bcrypt
    PE         2e3540000-       2e364f000   Deferred        shlwapi
    PE         2e8f10000-       2e948f000   Deferred        ole32
    PE         2edf00000-       2ee163000   Deferred        dxgi
    PE         2f1fa0000-       2f1fbe000   Deferred        version
    PE         30c980000-       30c98f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
    PE         3126f0000-       312744000   Deferred        shcore
    PE         316370000-       316382000   Deferred        psapi
    PE         316ce0000-       316cf0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1
    PE         327020000-       3271a4000   Deferred        combase
    PE         32a700000-       32a7bc000   Deferred        sechost
    PE         330260000-       330387000   Deferred        advapi32
    PE         346ba0000-       346bea000   Deferred        jsproxy
    PE         351680000-       35168f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
    PE         358120000-       35825c000   Deferred        winhttp
    PE         359050000-       3593e2000   Deferred        d3d11
    PE         3785e0000-       3785fc000   Deferred        vulkan-1
    PE         39f580000-       39f58f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1
    PE         3af670000-       3af9dd000   Deferred        ucrtbase
    PE         3afd00000-       3afd62000   Deferred        imm32
    PE         3b8f00000-       3b909f000   Deferred        winmm
    PE      7f7014020000-    7f701402b000   Deferred        winspool
    PE      7f7015320000-    7f7015324000   Deferred        winevulkan
    PE      7f7015390000-    7f7015394000   Deferred        iphlpapi
    PE      7f711e030000-    7f711e034000   Deferred        winex11
    PE      7f711ea20000-    7f711f2f2000   Deferred        shell32
    PE      7f711ffb0000-    7f711ffb6000   Deferred        ws2_32
    
    Threads:
    process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
    00000038 services.exe
        0000003c    0
        00000040    0
        0000004c    0
        0000005c    0
        00000090    0
        000000b8    0
        000000d0    0
        000000e4    0
    
    00000044 winedevice.exe
        00000048    0
        00000054    0
        00000058    0
        00000060    0
    
    00000078 explorer.exe
        0000007c    0
        000000a4    0
        000000b0    0
    
    00000084 winedevice.exe
        0000008c    0
        00000094    0
        00000098    0
        0000009c    0
        000000a0    0
    
    000000a8 plugplay.exe
        000000ac    0
        000000bc    0
        000000c0    0
        000000c4    0
    
    000000c8 svchost.exe
        000000cc    0
        000000d4    0
        000000d8    0
    
    000000dc rpcss.exe
        000000e0    0
        000000e8    0
        000000ec    0
        000000f0    0
        000000f4    0
        000000f8    0
    
    00000100 (D) Z:\home\bugboy\Downloads\Terra Nil Windows (Standalone) 140323\Terra Nil.exe
        00000104    0 <==
        00000110    0
        00000114    0
        00000118    0
        0000011c    0
        00000120   -2
        00000124   -2
        00000128   -2
        0000012c   -2
        00000130   -2
        00000134   -2
        00000138   -2
        0000013c   -2
        00000140   -2
        00000144   -2
        00000148   -2
        0000014c   -2
        00000150   -2
        00000154   -2
        00000158   -2
        0000015c   -2
        00000164   -1
        00000168    0
        0000016c    0
        00000170    0
        00000174    0
        00000184    0
    
    00000108 UnityCrashHandler64.exe
        0000010c    0
        00000160    0
    
    System information:
        Wine build: wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
        Platform: x86_64
        Version: Windows 7
        Host system: Linux
        Host version: 5.19.0-50-generic
    
    Creaks:
      
    Unhandled exception: page fault on execute access to 0x00000000 in 64-bit code (0x0000000000000000).
    
    Register dump:
     rip:0000000000000000 rsp:000000000020f3f8 rbp:000000007d63db20 eflags:00010202 (  R- --  I   - - - )
     
    rax:00000000005f3e00 rbx:0000000000608b20 rcx:0000000062ec2400 rdx:000000000020f4e0
     
    rsi:000000000020f570 rdi:000000000020f470  r8:0000000000000000  r9:0000000000000000 
    r10:00000000006c0000
     r11:00000000005fb6c8 r12:0000000000000000 r13:000000000020f7a0 r14:0000000000000003 
    r15:0000000000000014
    
    Stack dump:
    0x000000000020f3f8:  00000003590d2e7b 00000001c8dd6430
    0x000000000020f408:  00000001c8dd6455 00007ff180223680
    0x000000000020f418:  000000018057e2a3 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f428:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f438:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f448:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f458:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000020f468:  0000000000000000 00000000005d7340
    0x000000000020f478:  0000000000000000 0000000000000014
    0x000000000020f488:  0000000000000000 000000007d62c800
    0x000000000020f498:  0000000000000000 0000000000000014
    0x000000000020f4a8:  0000000000000000 000000003b9fee6e
    
    Backtrace:
    =>0 0x0000000000000000 (0x000000007d63db20)
    0x0000000000000000: -- no code accessible --
    
    Modules:
    
    Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (146 modules)
    PE          60950000-        610ba000   Deferred        mono-2.0-bdwgc
    ELF         7a800000-        7aa0e000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
      \-PE          7a850000-        7aa0e000   \               opengl32
    PE          7b000000-        7b3fd000   Deferred        kernelbase
    PE          7b600000-        7b969000   Deferred        kernel32
    PE          7bc00000-        7bf3c000   Deferred        ntdll
    ELF         7d000000-        7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
    PE         140000000-       1400a3000   Deferred        creaks
    PE         180000000-       181981000   Deferred        unityplayer
    PE         1c8b40000-       1c8bb7000   Deferred        msacm32
    PE         1c8db0000-       1c9097000   Deferred        msvcrt
    PE         1d97a0000-       1d97ae000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
    PE         1dd3f0000-       1dd758000   Deferred        crypt32
    PE         1f51e0000-       1f5212000   Deferred        hid
    PE         21a7e0000-       21a9ce000   Deferred        setupapi
    PE         226310000-       22631e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
    PE         231ae0000-       231d60000   Deferred        rpcrt4
    PE         23d820000-       23dfc2000   Deferred        user32
    PE         2419a0000-       241b0c000   Deferred        wbemprox
    PE         25cf30000-       25cf3f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0
    PE         25d740000-       25d75f000   Deferred        dwmapi
    PE         26b4c0000-       26bbb9000   Deferred        gdi32
    PE         2739c0000-       273ec9000   Deferred        oleaut32
    PE         28ebe0000-       28ebef000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
    PE         29ea80000-       29ea8e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
    PE         2ba290000-       2ba29f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0
    PE         2d4d40000-       2d4d96000   Deferred        bcrypt
    PE         2e3540000-       2e364f000   Deferred        shlwapi
    PE         2e8f10000-       2e948f000   Deferred        ole32
    PE         2edf00000-       2ee163000   Deferred        dxgi
    PE         2f1fa0000-       2f1fbe000   Deferred        version
    PE         2fa030000-       2fa03e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0
    PE         30c980000-       30c98f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
    PE         3126f0000-       312744000   Deferred        shcore
    PE         316370000-       316382000   Deferred        psapi
    PE         316ce0000-       316cf0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1
    PE         327020000-       3271a4000   Deferred        combase
    PE         32a700000-       32a7bc000   Deferred        sechost
    PE         330260000-       330387000   Deferred        advapi32
    PE         346ba0000-       346bea000   Deferred        jsproxy
    PE         351680000-       35168f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
    PE         358120000-       35825c000   Deferred        winhttp
    PE         359050000-       3593e2000   Deferred        d3d11
    PE         3785e0000-       3785fc000   Deferred        vulkan-1
    PE         39f580000-       39f58f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1
    PE         3af670000-       3af9dd000   Deferred        ucrtbase
    PE         3afd00000-       3afd62000   Deferred        imm32
    PE         3b8f00000-       3b909f000   Deferred        winmm
    ELF     7ff0abae2000-    7ff0abb08000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
    ELF     7ff0abb08000-    7ff0abc46000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
    ELF     7ff0abc46000-    7ff0abc51000   Deferred        libcap.so.2
    ELF     7ff0abc51000-    7ff0abc71000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
    ELF     7ff0abc71000-    7ff0abd38000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
    ELF     7ff0abd38000-    7ff0abd4c000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
    ELF     7ff0abd4c000-    7ff0abd53000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
    ELF     7ff0abd53000-    7ff0abda1000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
    ELF     7ff0abda1000-    7ff0abdaf000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
    ELF     7ff0abdaf000-    7ff0abdb5000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
    ELF     7ff0abdb5000-    7ff0abde4000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
    ELF     7ff0abde4000-    7ff0abeaf000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
    ELF     7ff0abeaf000-    7ff0abec3000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
    ELF     7ff0abec3000-    7ff0abf17000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
    ELF     7ff0abf17000-    7ff0abfb5000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
    ELF     7ff0abfb5000-    7ff0ac000000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
      \-PE      7ff0abfc0000-    7ff0ac000000   \               winspool
    ELF     7ff0b0003000-    7ff0b0011000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
    ELF     7ff0b0027000-    7ff0b005b000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
      \-PE      7ff0b0030000-    7ff0b005b000   \               iphlpapi
    ELF     7ff0b09ac000-    7ff0b100e000   Deferred        libvulkan_lvp.so
    ELF     7ff0b100e000-    7ff0b8000000   Deferred        libllvm-15.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fc1c7000-    7ff0fca1f000   Deferred        libvulkan_intel.so
    ELF     7ff0fca1f000-    7ff0fe63d000   Deferred        libicudata.so.70
    ELF     7ff0fe63d000-    7ff0fe838000   Deferred        libicuuc.so.70
    ELF     7ff0fe838000-    7ff0fea1a000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
    ELF     7ff0fea1a000-    7ff0fea4c000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.6
    ELF     7ff0fea4c000-    7ff0fea86000   Deferred        libedit.so.2
    ELF     7ff0fea86000-    7ff0feaa6000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fecd0000-    7ff0fece6000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
    ELF     7ff0fece6000-    7ff0feceb000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
    ELF     7ff0feceb000-    7ff0fecf0000   Deferred        libxcb-shm.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fecf0000-    7ff0fed03000   Deferred        libxcb-randr.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fed03000-    7ff0fed0d000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fed0d000-    7ff0fed17000   Deferred        libxcb-xfixes.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fed17000-    7ff0fed1c000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fed1c000-    7ff0fedeb000   Deferred        libzstd.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fedeb000-    7ff0fedfc000   Deferred        libwayland-client.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fedfc000-    7ff0fee03000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
    ELF     7ff0fee03000-    7ff0fee21000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fee21000-    7ff0fee2d000   Deferred        libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
    ELF     7ff0fee2d000-    7ff0ff594000   Deferred        libvulkan_radeon.so
    ELF     7ff0ff651000-    7ff0ff65f000   Deferred        libvklayer_mesa_device_select.so
    ELF     7ff0ff65f000-    7ff0ff6cd000   Deferred        libvulkan.so.1
    ELF     7ff0ff6cd000-    7ff0ff740000   Deferred        winevulkan<elf>
      \-PE      7ff0ff6e0000-    7ff0ff740000   \               winevulkan
    ELF     7ff21f940000-    7ff21f945000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f98b000-    7ff21f993000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
    ELF     7ff21f993000-    7ff21f99f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f99f000-    7ff21f9b3000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
    ELF     7ff21f9b3000-    7ff21f9b8000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f9b8000-    7ff21f9c5000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
    ELF     7ff21f9c5000-    7ff21f9d2000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f9d2000-    7ff21f9d9000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f9d9000-    7ff21f9de000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
    ELF     7ff21f9de000-    7ff21f9eb000   Deferred        libmd.so.0
    ELF     7ff21f9eb000-    7ff21fa03000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
    ELF     7ff21fa03000-    7ff21fa0b000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fa0b000-    7ff21fa11000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fa11000-    7ff21fa3b000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
    ELF     7ff21fa3b000-    7ff21fb7b000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fb7b000-    7ff21fb90000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fb90000-    7ff21fc4d000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
      \-PE      7ff21fba0000-    7ff21fc4d000   \               winex11
    ELF     7ff21fc4d000-    7ff21fc5a000   Deferred        libffi.so.8
    ELF     7ff21fc5a000-    7ff21fcdc000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
    ELF     7ff21fcdc000-    7ff21fd24000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fd24000-    7ff21fd6a000   Deferred        libnettle.so.8
    ELF     7ff21fd6a000-    7ff21fd82000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
    ELF     7ff21fd82000-    7ff21ff2c000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
    ELF     7ff21ff2c000-    7ff21ff4d000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
    ELF     7ff21ff4d000-    7ff220088000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
    ELF     7ff220088000-    7ff220273000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
    ELF     7ff220330000-    7ff220339000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
    ELF     7ff220339000-    7ff22036a000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
    ELF     7ff22036a000-    7ff2203b4000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
    ELF     7ff2203b4000-    7ff2203d7000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
    ELF     7ff2203d7000-    7ff2203e5000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
    ELF     7ff2203e5000-    7ff220401000   Deferred        libz.so.1
    ELF     7ff220401000-    7ff22043c000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
    ELF     7ff22043c000-    7ff220504000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
    ELF     7ff220504000-    7ff22051c000   Deferred        crypt32.so
    ELF     7ff22051c000-    7ff220539000   Deferred        bcrypt.so
    ELF     7ff220539000-    7ff22057e000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
      \-PE      7ff220540000-    7ff22057e000   \               ws2_32
    ELF     7ff22067e000-    7ff2210a7000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
      \-PE      7ff2206a0000-    7ff2210a7000   \               shell32
    ELF     7ff2210a7000-    7ff2210d6000   Deferred        gdi32.so
    ELF     7ff2210d6000-    7ff2210f4000   Deferred        ucrtbase.so
    ELF     7ff2210f4000-    7ff221112000   Deferred        msvcrt.so
    ELF     7ff221212000-    7ff221229000   Deferred        user32.so
    ELF     7ff221429000-    7ff22159f000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
    ELF     7ff221d12000-    7ff221d3d000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
    ELF     7ff221d3d000-    7ff221e24000   Deferred        libm.so.6
    ELF     7ff221e24000-    7ff221e3f000   Deferred        libunwind.so.8
    ELF     7ff221e3f000-    7ff221edb000   Deferred        ntdll.so
    ELF     7ff221ede000-    7ff222106000   Deferred        libc.so.6
    ELF     7ff22211e000-    7ff22215a000   Deferred        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    
    Threads:
    process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
    
    00000038 services.exe
        0000003c    0
        00000040    0
        0000004c    0
        00000090    0
        0000009c    0
        000000bc    0
        000000d4    0
        000000e8    0
    
    00000044 winedevice.exe
        00000048    0
        00000054    0
        00000058    0
        0000005c    0
    
    00000060 explorer.exe
        00000064    0
        000000a0    0
        000000ac    0
    
    00000084 winedevice.exe
        00000088    0
        00000094    0
        00000098    0
        000000a4    0
        000000a8    0
    
    000000b4 plugplay.exe
        000000b8    0
        000000c0    0
        000000c4    0
        000000c8    0
    
    000000cc svchost.exe
        000000d0    0
        000000d8    0
        000000dc    0
    
    000000e0 rpcss.exe
        000000e4    0
        000000ec    0
        000000f0    0
        000000f4    0
        000000f8    0
        000000fc    0
    
    00000104 (D) C:\GOG Games\Creaks\Creaks.exe
        00000108    0 <==
        00000114    0
        00000118    0
        0000011c    0
        00000120    0
        00000124   -2
        00000128   -2
        0000012c   -2
        00000130   -2
        00000134   -2
        00000138   -2
        0000013c   -2
        00000140   -2
        00000144   -2
        00000148   -2
        0000014c   -2
        00000150   -2
        00000154   -2
        00000158   -2
        0000015c   -2
        00000160   -2
        00000164   -1
        00000168    0
        00000170    0
        00000174    0
        00000178    0
        00000188    0
    
    0000010c UnityCrashHandler64.exe
        00000110    0
        0000016c    0
    
    System information:
        Wine build: wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
        Platform: x86_64
        Version: Windows 7
        Host system: Linux
        Host version: 5.15.0-76-generic
```

Comment: Does it happen for every software, or just for this game? Do basic software like notepad run properly?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Basic software that came preinstalled with the launcher seems to still work. On second inspection that seems to be one or two games that still work. However, the lions share do not work with Wine, with almost all of those previously working before I updated Ubuntu.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: @waltinator While that was one of my first thoughts, they all worked before I updated to Ubuntu 22. I also checked with the wine database and multiple programs were rated platinum, so this does not seem to be a compatability issue.